# Iterating Over Each Word In a String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Do I need to have more lines of code just to get each word, in a string, to be capitalize using ruby?

```
h = "hello world and good morning"
h.capitalize #=> Hello world and good morning
```

I need all words be capitalized. How? Nothing has been mentioned [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-capitalize).

Do I need a messy code to extract each word, using regex, convert to capitalize then put back into string? That sounds messy. Is there a simple method for this?

Comment: Never seen that in my many searches.

Comment: It's not always straightforward to find out if there's a duplicate or not. :-) Nothing wrong in asking your question anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = "hello world and good morning" 
h.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
#=> "Hello World And Good Morning"
```

Comment: As I posted my answer so did you!

Comment: I'll mark yours correct in few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method using `gsub`:

```
h = "hello world and good morning"
h.gsub(/(?<=\A|\s)\w/, &:upcase)
# => "Hello World And Good Morning"
```

It basically runs the `upcase` method on any "word character" (`\w`) that comes after either the start of the string (`\A`) or a space (`\s`).

Answer (score 0):

If there a post elsewhere on this website then you can close this but I have found the answer:

```
h.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
#=> Hello World And Good Morning
```